# Caching of password-protected data using Varnish

Tags: caching, varnish

I want to serve a generated resource only to users with administrative privileges, and I want Varnish to cache it for me, so the back end doesn't have to regenerate it every time it is requested. I don't want to perform caching at back end either as I have Varnish for this purpose.

Here is pseudo-code for what my back end does:

```
if (authenticated(cookie)) 
{
    if (stale)
    {
        regenerate_and_send()
    }
    else
    {
         not_modified()
    }
}
else
{
     access_denied()
}
```

So I'm thinking of Varnish performing validations (conditional GETs) and back end responding with "Not modified", "Access denied" or "200 OK" HTTP statuses (regenerating the resource in the last case of course).

I need Varnish to pass cookie to the back end but to ignore the cookie when storing the resource in cache, so only one copy is stored.

How can I do this?

It's easy to enforce validation and write the backend logic. How do I deal with cookies in Varnish so they don't affect caching but still get passed to the back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Varnish won't look in the cache if a request has a cookie, so you have to write your own vcl configuration file.

If I understand your question correctly, the resource in question can be served to all admin-privileged users. The story here is; each user has a different session cookie and varnish has no way of knowing which session cookie is admin-privileged. You can do (at least) two things:

1. Set an 'admin=yourmagicstringhere' cookie if a user obtains admin privileges. Make Varnish capable of verifying the magicstring is correct, and do a lookup/fetch for the request accordingly for the resource. This has some security disadvantages but works.
2. Always forward the request to the back-end (no need to lookup/store in cache), the back-end generates an <ESI:include "real-url"> request if the user is admin-privileged, which is resolved. Alternative to ESI you can have the back-end generate some other OK response and do a restart in which you can do a lookup/fetch/deliver.

Comment: I went the ESI way and it worked! Thank you. As for restarting approach - I think it is prone to introducing restarting loops by mistake.